# Making group-shared directories writeable with Python and os.umask

Tags: python, unix, permissions, file-permissions

Currently the directory is

`/var/www/html/sitename_com/`. This directory is owned by meder.meder. Not sure under what umask I was when I created this dir.

My script is bound to pyinotify and after I `mkdir www` it binds an event handler to set the:

group to `web` and user to `publisher` through:

```
  uid = pwd.getpwnam( 'publisher' ).pw_uid
  gid = grp.getgrnam( 'web' ).gr_gid

  os.chown( path, uid, gid )
```

umask to `0002`:

```
  current_umask = os.umask(0)
  print 'umask is ' + str(current_umask)

  os.umask(0002)
  current_umask = os.umask(0)
  print 'updated umask is ' + str(current_umask)
```

I also `chmod` the permissions. 0664 for files and 0775 for directories, through:

```
    os.chmod( path, int( "0664", 8 ) ) # files
```

After I `mkdir` www, here are my log reports:

```
pre fix its 0755
fixing permission to 0775
fix path is /var/www/html/sitename/www
post fix its 0775
umask is 0
updated umask is 2
former user is meder and former group is meder
attempting to set user to publisher and group to web
post chown user is publisher and former group is web
```

I am unable to create a file in `www` with my `meder` user, who is in the group `web`.

```
cd www
meder@oskol:/var/www/html/sitename_com/www$ touch file.jpg
touch: cannot touch `file.jpg': Permission denied
```

Do I have to make `web` the primary group for my `meder` user? Did I mess up the umask part by not prefixing enough 0s?

Comment: Actually upon writing all this, I think I know why. The `umask` when it gets CREATED by *my* user is not what I intend it to be. I need to actually change the `umask` AFTER the directory has been created, because I'm binding this event handler to when the user creates files/directories. Is this right?

Comment: a simple test is ls -ld /var/www/html/sitename_com/www

Comment: Returns `drwxrwxr-x 2 publisher web 4096 Mar 29 13:09`

Comment: and whats the output of $groups meder?

Comment: `meder : meder cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev netdev bluetooth scanner web`. Did you read my first comment? Do I need to do the python equivalent of `chmod g+s` on the dir after its been created since I am not programmatically creating, but modifying after creation?

Comment: The problem is meder needs to be in the group publisher

Comment: But `web` is the group and `publisher` is the user. You sure??

Comment: whoops, yes your right

Comment: What about having to do the python equivalent of `chmod g+s` on the directory?